# Run promises inside Refresh Control in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Here I have a promise inside refresh control method,

```
const Component = () => {
 const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);

 const onRefresh = useCallback(() => {
    setRefreshing(true);
    getData();
    setRefreshing(false);
  }, []);
  
  return (
   <ScrollView
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
        }>...</ScrollView>
  );
}
```

How to wait for the `getData()` function and after that set refresh to false? Problem is it isn't waiting for the `getData()` function to finish. `(getData() is a promise)`

the getData() function,

```
const getData = () => {
 axios.get(`https://somedomain.com/fetch/user/1`).then(res => {
  ...
 }
}
```

Comment: `useCallback(async () => { setRefreshing(true); await getData(); setRefreshing(false); }, [])`

Comment: I tried that too but didn't work still instantly hiding the refresh control

Comment: did you try getData().then(res=>setRefreshing(false))

Comment: Yeah I tried that too gave me an error saying 'cannot read the properties of undefined of then'

Comment: is your `getData` method is an async function ? or are you using `Promise`  to handle get data ?

Comment: Can you add your `getData` method here ? I guess you are calling any api in the `getData`, just want to see how are you calling that.

Comment: @Kailash It is a promise

Comment: Okay, then add your `setRefreshing(false)` just after you are resolving or rejecting the promise. And remove it from `onRefresh`

Comment: @MishenThakshana It's not. You may have a promise somewhere, but you fail to return it from `getData` and return `undefined` instead. Please edit `getData`'s implementation into the question.

Comment: I have updated my answer, no problem with the request it's working fine

Comment: It should be `return axios.get()` or you should drop the curly braces around the arrow function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getData()` is a promise inside a function. In that method, I returned the promise and did like this to solve this issue,

```
const onRefresh = useCallback(async () => {
    setRefreshing(true);
    getData().then(() => {
     setRefreshing(false);
    });
 }, []);
```

Comment: It could only work if you will make your `getData` async or return a promise. As per the `getData` definition in your question it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
const Component = () => {
 const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);

const getData = () => {
 axios.get(`https://somedomain.com/fetch/user/1`).then(res => {
  ...
  setRefreshing(false);
 }
}

 const onRefresh = useCallback(() => {
    setRefreshing(true);
    getData();
  }, []);
  
  return (
   <ScrollView
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl refreshing={refreshing} onRefresh={onRefresh} />
        }>...</ScrollView>
  );
}
```

**Alternative**:

```
const getData = async () => {
 const response = await axios.get(`https://somedomain.com/fetch/user/1`);
//Handle your response here
}

 const onRefresh = useCallback(async () => {
    setRefreshing(true);
    await getData();
    setRefreshing(false);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Problem is getData() function is in my context file

Comment: Okay, I will edit it then

Comment: change your `getData` method likewise and  `onRefresh` to async method. There is one more alternative, if you are want to know I can suggest that well, Simply handle a promise there in `getData` and keep the definition same as it was earlier.